# C# event and delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I want to detach the custom event but could not detach. Below I am using `-=` to detach the event. I assume after this, the `TextChanged2` method should not be invoked as I have unregistered the event. Is my understanding wrong?

```
public delegate void TextChangedEventHandler1(object sender, TextBoxargs ta);
public event TextChangedEventHandler1 TextChanged1;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TextChanged1 -= new  TextChangedEventHandler1(TextChanged2);
    TextChanged2(sender, e);
}

public void TextChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: You're calling the `TextChanged2` event manually, is this what you intend?

Comment: please show entire class code, because this peace of code has any sense 4 me...

Comment: do mark answer as accepted if you got the infomation you want

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing is right. But using the following line of the code you can detach the event handler.

```
this.TextChanged1 -= new  TextChangedEventHandler1(TextChanged2);
```

But on the second line you called the function directly so that it called the textchange2 function:

```
TextChanged2(sender, e);
```

Comment: if I remove the call TextChanged2(sender, e); 
the method is not called even a single time.

Comment: @user359562: man, if you call a method, it is executed, what is the problem?

Comment: have you register event handler by using this line : this.TextChanged1 += new  TextChangedEventHandler1(TextChanged2); because its require to register to call event handling function

Comment: My question is if I register the event as in this case, there is no need to explicitly call TextChanged2 method right ? if so, then what is the problem in above code

Comment: there is no need to call the event explicitly here if you registred it already. i already explained about your code in my answer

Comment: @user359562: tell us what do you try do, cause there are any sense of your code.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to detach the custom event but
>   could not detach.

You do. You detach very well your event.

> TextChanged2 method should not be
>   invoked as I have unregistered the
>   event.

It should not be invoked when this.textChanged1, but **you invoke it yourself** by calling `TextChanged2(sender, e);`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
this.TextChanged1 -= TextChanged2;
```

Comment: This is no different from what he already has. The `new TextChangedEventHandler1(...)` is now syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you give some more reasonable names to your methods, controls, and events. I could imagine half the confusion here stems from confusing names.

For example, in one comment to an answer, you mention that if you don't call the `TextChanged2` event handler (for the `TextChanged1` event...) explicitly, it will never get called. This would lead to the question *when*, and *where*, you raise the `TextChanged1` event. If you have indeed subscribed the `TextChanged2` handler to the `TextChanged1` event with the `+=` operator, then the handler *will* be invoked as soon as the event is raised.